# Problem of how to manipulate Taylor/McLaurin series

Tags: manipulate, data, series-expansion

I'm new to Mathematica so I don't know very well the program itself.
I would like to manipulate as he does this person in youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCJHvQaGNiQ 
But I put all the information but nothing happens, I don't know if there are some changes from Mathematica 6 vs. the Mathematica 9.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Surely you realise that nobody can answer this question the way you ask it. What does "I put all the data" mean? What data? Surely if you type in the code shown in the video it works?

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not a english speaker, so I didn't know if I was telling it correctly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Sin@x, Normal@Series[Sin@u, {u, x0, n}] /. u -> x}, {x, -2 Pi,  2 Pi}, 
      PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2, 2}}, 
      Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point@{x0, Sin@x0}}], 
     {n, 0, 10, 1}, {x0, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la informacion, solo queria preguntarte una cosa mas. En el video se ve como tambien mueve el punto (x) en el cual quiere que se haga la aproximacion. ?Sabrias como se hace eso? Y lo que pone de informacion para el grafico, ha variado algo desde el Mathematica 6 al 9? Lo siento por los fallos ortograficos   Saludos desde España!

Comment: @JMC Take a look at the "new" version

Comment: Ok thank you very much!I will try it now! Gracias!